# Trouble with #ifdef across multiple files

Tags: c, logging, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

`util.h` contains the following code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOGGER() MACRO_WRAP(printf("Entering %s\n", __func__))
#else
#define LOGGER() MACRO_WRAP()
#endif
```

`foo.c` contains this code:

```
void foo_start(foo *m)
{
    LOGGER();

    do_action(m, START);
}
```

and then `foo_unit_tests.c` contains calls to `foo_start()`. I'd like to be able to `#define DEBUG` at the top of the relevant files -- i.e. I want it to be turned on for unit tests, but not for the main code.

I can't get it to work. Putting `#define DEBUG` at the top of `foo_unit_tests.c` doesn't produce the desired behavior. The only way I can get it to work is by putting `#define DEBUG` either at the top of `util.h` or `foo.c`, both of which are much messier than I would like.

What am I missing here? I thought that the macro defined in the `.c` file would be visible inside of all of the `.h` files that it included.

Comment: It's not the `.h` file that includes the `.c` file. It's the other way around. And the preprocessor does *textual* substitution. It is not a compiler. It is not a linker. Think about these facts, and you will see why you got the errors you got.

Comment: Okay. Why the downvotes and the close vote? I submitted relevant, short code snippets and demonstrated my attempts to solve the problem, I'm not really sure what's off topic about that?

Comment: Not one of the downvoters, but the downvotes wouldn't have been about the off-topicness of the question. I do see effort on your part to address the problem, so I don't really agree with the close vote either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have the `#define` at the beginning of all your files that need that macro defined, or through including a `.h` file that has it in it.

If you want a cleaner way of doing that, then it is probably better to use the compiler flags to set environmental variables.

For example

```
icpc -DDEBUG=whatever source.c ...
```

Or even better, you can enable this compiler flag though an environmental variable in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

foo_unit_tests.c most likely does not include foo.c, so the #define there is never seen when compiling foo_unit_tests.c

Answer (score 0):

define your normal logger somewhere.. the in the unit test..

```
#undef LOGGER()

#define LOGGER(x) fprintf(stdout, x)
```

or alternately you could do something like:

```
#ifdef UNITTEST
    #define LOGGER ...
#else
    #define LOGGER ...
#endif
```

and you pass in the UNITTEST macro from the build env when you build test